# Virtual machine freezes computer

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, genymotion

I am using android studio and using Genymotion as my virtual device in Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS. I was having a good time with Genymotion. Since a week as i run Virtual machine to use Genymotion computer Suddenly Freezes. But as soon as i close the Virtual machine machine starts working smoothly.What can be the problem? is it the problem with my machine?

Answer (score 2):

Genymotion is a known resource hog. Maybe you need to add more RAM. Then you can allocate more RAM to the VirtualBox VM.

A guest OS in VirtualBox can be configured to use up to 256MB video memory. To increase the video memory to 256MB, open the terminal and type:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Name of VM" --vram 256
```

You can also configure the number of processors in the VirtualBox settings.

Comment: its already 4GB it was working well before...

Comment: It will work faster with 8GB RAM. Storing the VirtualBox files on an SSD speeds up performance too.

Comment: yes i now it but i mean to say that it was working fine even with 4 gb but now it always freezes. The solution only i have is to Format my device which i cannot do it. Is there any resources for this to run as before?

Comment: lol, i have a ssd, 8gb ram and Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti GPU on it, and the vm can use 4 cores 8gb of ram and all my gpu and even it freezes

Comment: In VMware Workstation 12 and later for graphics-intensive applications, 2GB of video memory can be allocated for additional workload processing power.